# synchronous mysql queries in node when creating a pdf

Tags: mysql, node.js, pdfkit

hi i'm trying to write a PDF file using data from MySQL database but when i run the script it give me that i end the PDF file creation and after that i tried to insert data to it ..... i think it's because MySQL in node is Asynchronous . is there any solution for this ?
here is my code ...

```
var project_ID = 1;
var PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');
$('#pdf').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var pdf = new PDFDocument;
    pdf.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/../MyFile.pdf'));
    var option;
    switch ($("input[name=report-type]:checked").val()) {
        case 'all-issues':
            option = {project_id: project_ID};
            break;

        case  'all-issues-customer':
            option = {project_id: project_ID, customer: customer};
            break;
    }
    connection.getConnection(function (err, conn) { //make connection to DB
        if (err) { //error handling
            showNotification('error connecting: ' + err.stack, 'danger', 'glyphicon glyphicon-tasks');
            return;
        }
        conn.query('SELECT issues.id, issues.dbid , issues.date, issues.charm , issues.defect ,issues.key , issues.status, issues.summary, issues.description , actions.date as action_date, actions.description as action_desc FROM issues' +
            ' INNER JOIN actions on issues.id = actions.issue_id WHERE ? ', [option], function (error, data) {
            if (error) {
                showNotification('Error :' + error, 'danger', 'glyphicon glyphicon-tasks');
            } else {
                var lastID = -1;
                data.forEach(function (data) {
                    if (lastID !== data.id) {
                        lastID = data.id;
                        pdf.addPage();
                        pdf.text('Number :' + data.dbid).moveDown();
                        pdf.text('Customers :            ');
                        pdf.text('Baseline :            ');
                        pdf.text('Error/Wish :            ' + data.key).moveDown();
                        pdf.text('Charm :  ' + data.charm + ' / Defect :  ' + data.defect + '                   Status : ' + data.status);
                        pdf.text('Summary :                ' + data.summary);
                        pdf.text('Description :            ' + data.description).moveDown();
                        pdf.text('Actions/ History :').moveDown();
                    }
                    pdf.text('          - date        : ' + convertDate(data.date));
                    pdf.text('            description : ' + data.description).moveDown();
                })
            }
        });
        conn.release();
    });
    pdf.end();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of the asynchronous nature of Node.js.  You can quickly alter your code in a few areas to fix it though.  You have some calls like `conn.release()` and `pdf.end()` that fall *outside of the your callback*.

In the code below I've moved `conn.release()` and `pdf.end()` to the last lines of your mysql connection callback.

```
var project_ID = 1;
var PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');
$('#pdf').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var pdf = new PDFDocument;
    pdf.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/../MyFile.pdf'));
    var option;
    switch ($("input[name=report-type]:checked").val()) {
        case 'all-issues':
            option = {project_id: project_ID};
            break;

        case  'all-issues-customer':
            option = {project_id: project_ID, customer: customer};
            break;
    }
    connection.getConnection(function (err, conn) { //make connection to DB
        if (err) { //error handling
            showNotification('error connecting: ' + err.stack, 'danger', 'glyphicon glyphicon-tasks');
            return;
        }
        conn.query('SELECT issues.id, issues.dbid , issues.date, issues.charm , issues.defect ,issues.key , issues.status, issues.summary, issues.description , actions.date as action_date, actions.description as action_desc FROM issues' +
            ' INNER JOIN actions on issues.id = actions.issue_id WHERE ? ', [option], function (error, data) {
            if (error) {
                showNotification('Error :' + error, 'danger', 'glyphicon glyphicon-tasks');
            } else {
                var lastID = -1;
                data.forEach(function (data) {
                    if (lastID !== data.id) {
                        lastID = data.id;
                        pdf.addPage();
                        pdf.text('Number :' + data.dbid).moveDown();
                        pdf.text('Customers :            ');
                        pdf.text('Baseline :            ');
                        pdf.text('Error/Wish :            ' + data.key).moveDown();
                        pdf.text('Charm :  ' + data.charm + ' / Defect :  ' + data.defect + '                   Status : ' + data.status);
                        pdf.text('Summary :                ' + data.summary);
                        pdf.text('Description :            ' + data.description).moveDown();
                        pdf.text('Actions/ History :').moveDown();
                    }
                    pdf.text('          - date        : ' + convertDate(data.date));
                    pdf.text('            description : ' + data.description).moveDown();
                })
            }
            conn.release();
            pdf.end();
        });
    });
});
```

That should ensure that those calls aren't made until after the callback logic is done.  *Note* that if you had a callback (or more) within that callback you often times have to make sure those functions are called inside of those callbacks.  You'll find yourself in the middle of [Callback Hell](http://callbackhell.com/) quite often.

Best of luck to you!